# kSOAP Marshalling help needed

Tags: soap, java-me, ksoap

Does anyone have a good complex object marshalling example using the kSOAP package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although this example is not compilable and complete, the basic idea is to have a class that tells kSOAP how to turn an XML tag into an object (i.e. readInstance()) and how to turn an object into an XML tag (i.e. writeInstance()).

```
public class MarshalBase64File implements Marshal {

  public static Class FILE_CLASS = File.class;

  public Object readInstance(XmlPullParser parser, String namespace, String name, PropertyInfo expected)
      throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    return Base64.decode(parser.nextText());
  }

  public void writeInstance(XmlSerializer writer, Object obj) throws IOException {
    File file = (File)obj;
    int total = (int)file.length();
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte b[] = new byte[4096];
    int pos = 0;
    int num = b.length;
    if ((pos + num) > total) {
      num = total - pos;
    }
    int len = in.read(b, 0, num);
    while ((len != -1) && ((pos + len) < total)) {
      writer.text(Base64.encode(b, 0, len, null).toString());
      pos += len;
      if ((pos + num) > total) {
        num = total - pos;
      }
      len = in.read(b, 0, num);
    }
    if (len != -1) {
      writer.text(Base64.encode(b, 0, len, null).toString());
    }
  }

  public void register(SoapSerializationEnvelope cm) {
    cm.addMapping(cm.xsd, "base64Binary", MarshalBase64File.FILE_CLASS, this);
  }
}
```

Later, when you invoke the SOAP service, you'll map the object type (in this case, File objects) to the marshalling class.  The SOAP envelope will automatically match the object type of each argument and, if it is not a built-in type, invoke the associated marshaller to convert it to/from XML.

```
public class MarshalDemo {

  public String storeFile(File file) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    SoapObject soapObj = new SoapObject("http://www.example.com/ws/service/file/1.0", "storeFile");
    soapObj.addProperty("file", file);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    new MarshalBase64File().register(envelope);
    envelope.encodingStyle = SoapEnvelope.ENC;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapObj);

    HttpTransport ht = new HttpTransport(new URL(server, "/soap/file"));
    ht.call("http://www.example.com/ws/service/file/1.0/storeFile", envelope);

    String retVal = "";
    SoapObject writeResponse = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
    Object obj = writeResponse.getProperty("statusString");
    if (obj instanceof SoapPrimitive) {
      SoapPrimitive statusString = (SoapPrimitive)obj;
      String content = statusString.toString();
      retVal = content;
    }
    return retVal;
  }
}
```

In this case, I am using Base64 encoding to marshal File objects.

Comment: Nice answer +1 @Dan Howard

Comment: how to write marshal for Custom Class containing arraylist?